# magento 2.x using composer in windows localhost

Tags: magento2, composer, xampp

I not able to set the Megento 2.4.0 as the setup button is not displaying on screen after downloading megento.
Attaching screenshot for the reference of Where am I actually stuck .
[image: error facing]

Comment: Hello, first your extract your magento 2 zip and open the command line and run below command :  **`php bin/magento setup:install --base-url= http://localhost/yourrootfoldername/ --db-host=localhost --db-name= magento2 --db-user= root --db-password= password --admin-firstname=test --admin-lastname=testadmin --admin-email=test@gmail.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --cleanup-database --sales-order-increment-prefix="ORD$" --session-save=db --use-rewrites=1`**

Comment: HI Mohit I tried that but getting an error

Comment: Too many arguments, expected arguments "command".